# web service will soon be replaced for android app

Tags: android, design-patterns, parse-platform

I am designing an Android app which sends objects to a parse server. later on, this parse server will be replaced by a REST server. This will cause duplication of code and extra work re-writing code to point to this new Android server. Is there a design pattern or any suggestions which I can use to minimize all this code refactoring ?

Comment: you should create a proxy for parse server and in your application you should call the proxy and later you just change in your proxy from parse to your rest server

Comment: Pick the appropriate pattern from this page: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/structural_patterns

Comment: However, this is probably too broad a question for Stack Overflow which tends to focus on specific programming details rather than broad architectural issues.